# What is the difference between coretemp-isa-0000 and "Virtual" temperatures?

Tags: overheating, fan, temperature

I notice when I run thinkfan on my laptop, it has no problem running with just the coretemp sensors, but wont run with the virtual sensors.

Do I need to include the virtual sensors in my thinkfan.config file or is it okay to manage fan speed / temperature levels without them?

Here is the output of sensors:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +43.0°C

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +35.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +31.0°C
```